# Abrir pagina na mesma janela

Tags: html, html5

Tenho um button onde gostaria que ele direcionasse para uma outra pagina quando clicado e a alternativa que eu encontrei foi usando o om click, mas acontece que ele abre em outra janela e eu preciso que abra na mesma janela.

Como fazer para abrir na mesma janela?

```
<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('menu.html')">Login</button>
```

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está difícil de interpretar. Vc tem um `button` do tipo **submit**, este tipo de botão submete algo, geralmente é colocado em um `form` para submetê-lo. Se vc colocar esta função **onclick** em um submit, o form é submetido, não haverá tempo para executar a função que vc quer. Vc quer abrir um menu certo, na mesma página, em outra página, o que quer realmente fazer?

Comment: tenta usar assim "<a href="menu.html"><button type="submit">Login</button></a>"

Comment: Por qual motivo utilizou `<button>` e não `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.location.href=''` no lugar de `window.open('menu.html')`, `window.open` vai abrir uma nova janela e não é isso que você quer...
Você pode usar também `window.location.replace('menu.html')`, porém este substituirá a pagina atual no histórico do navegador, fazendo com que não seja possivel voltar para a pagina após clicar no botão.

**Opção 1** `window.location.href=''`**:**

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='menu.html'">Login</button>
```

**Opção 2** `window.location.replace()`**:**

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.replace('menu.html')">Login</button>
```

**Opção 3, um botão feito de link.**

```css
.btnlogin {
    background:#000;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:4px 6px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="menu.html" class="btnlogin">Login</a>
```

Comment: A resposta sobre a pergunta ja foi respondida, mas fiquei com uma duvida.                 O riquired dos imputs funciona com as opções 1 ou 2?

Comment: o required é individual do input, o botão não afeta ele, a menos que algo o mude, como um script `document.querySelector("input").required = false` ou algo do tipo